# Python multiprocessing queues and streaming data

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am connecting to an API that sends streaming data in string format. This stream runs for about 9 hours per day. Each string that is sent (about 1-5, 40 charter stings per second) need to be parsed and certain values need to extracted. Those values are then stored in a list which is parsed and data is retrieved at various intervals to create another list which needs to be parsed. What is the best way to accomplish this with miltiprocessing, queues? Is there a better way?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import requests
data_stream = requests.get("http://myDataStreamUrl", stream=True)
lines = data_stream.iter_lines()
 first_line = next(lines)
 for line in lines:
   find what i need and append to first_list
 def parse_first_list_and create_second_list():
    find what i need in first_list to create second list
  def parse_second_list():
      find what i need
```